# Let $\sum^\infty_{n=1}x_n$ where all the terms are positive. Prove that if this series is convergent, so is $\sum^\infty_{n=1}x_n^2.$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $$\sum^\infty_{n=1}x_n$$
where all the terms are positive.

1. Prove that if this series is convergent, so is 
   $$\sum^\infty_{n=1}x_n^2.$$
2. Prove that the previous statement does not necessarily hold the other way around.

I know how to approach this when the terms can also be negative but when the terms are now all positive, I don't even know how to start.

Comment: Hint: If its convergent, then what is $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:**

Since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n$ converges, there exists $N \in \Bbb{N}$ such that for all $n \ge N$ we have $x_n \le 1$. Hence $x_n^2 \le x_n$ so
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n^2 \le \sum_{n=1}^N x_n^2 + \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty x_n < +\infty.$$

To show that the converse doesn't hold, consider $x_n = \frac1n$.

Comment: Could we argue by invoking Cauchy-Schwarz?

Comment: @DaniloGregorin Yes, look at LPenguin's answer. We can get that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n^2 \le \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n\right)^2 < +\infty.$$

Answer (score 3):

Because $x_n$ is positive for all $n$
$$X_N=\sum_{n=1}^{N}x_n^{2}\leq \left ( \sum_{n=1}^{N}x_n \right )^{2} \leq \left ( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_n \right )^{2}$$
So $X_N$ is a monotonically increasing and bounded sequence, therefore convergent.

Answer (score 0):

If $S_1 = \sum^\infty_{n=1}x_n$ is convergent, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} = 0$ and there exists a $k$ such that $0<x_n<1 \ \forall n \geq k$. So you can split the sum into  $\sum^{k-1}_{n=1}x_n +  \sum^{\infty}_{n=k}x_n$. The first sum is clearly finite, so for the sum to be convergent, the second has to be as well.

Now consider $S_2 = \sum^\infty_{n=1}x^2_n = \sum^{k-1}_{n=1}x^2_n +  \sum^{\infty}_{n=k}x^2_n$. The first sum is clearly again finite. The second sum is smaller term for term than $\sum^{\infty}_{n=k}x_n$, so it clearly converges as well. Hence $S_2$ is also convergent.

For the other part, it is sufficient to provide a counter-example. An easy one is $\zeta(2)$ vs the harmonic series.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\sum_{n\ge 1}x_{n}$ is a series of positive terms and it converges we have $$\lim_{n \to \infty}x_n=0\implies \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{x_n^2}{x_n}=0$$
Now lets choose $\epsilon=1$, then $\exists N_0\in \mathbb N$ such that $$\frac{x_n^2}{x_n}\leq 1;\forall n\ge N_0\implies x_n^2\leq x_n, \forall n\ge N_0$$
(notice that all terms are positive here)
Then by this comparison we have
$$\lim_{M\to \infty}\sum_{n\ge N_0}^{M}x_{n}^2\leq \lim_{M\to \infty}\sum_{n\ge N_0}^{M}x_{n}<\infty$$
Hence 
$\sum^\infty_{n=1}x_n^2< \infty$. And for the second just take $x_n=\frac{1}{n}$